# Chronos "Force Run" via API

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

On Chronos WebUI, I can "Force Run" jobs and immediately get results.

Is it possible to perform "Force Run" via Chronos REST API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jobs can be manually triggered with a PUT to /scheduler/job/$JOB_NAME. For example:

```
curl -L -X PUT chronos-node:8080/scheduler/job/$JOB_NAME
```

See https://github.com/mesos/chronos#manually-starting-a-job.